# Get string length function (strlen) of a constant char array is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr

Let's see the simplified code directly (compiled by: GCC 6.3.0)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int arga, char* argv[]) {

    const char cs[] = "Hello";//define a constant c-style string 
    constexpr size_t newSize = strlen(cs) + strlen(" ");//Error

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler yielded an error:  **strlen(((const char*)(& cs)))** is not a constant expression

However, when I move the c-string definition to the global scope, then the problem is off.

```
.... 
const char cs[] = "Hello";

int main(int arga, char* argv[]) {
    constexpr size_t newSize = strlen(cs) + strlen(" ")//No Error
 ....
}
```

Can someone explain what happened? Why **strlen()** sees a globally defined constant c-string as a constant expression, but not the one in the stack?

Comment: I know little about `constexpr`, I just wonder how its size can be `constexpr` when the string itself isnt

Comment: I know GCC has a few functions like `strlen` that it will treat as builtins unless you pass a flag to disable it. Perhaps that only works for strings with static storage duration.

Comment: [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5236473b55a812e) does reject the code

Comment: GCC 6.3.0 is used

Comment: @user463035818, I believe strings can be used in constant expressions much like `i` can in `const int i = 5; int arr[i];`, despite there being no `constexpr`. Given a `constexpr` form of `strlen`, the string would have to have static storage duration in order for the conversion to a pointer to work out. Should you avoid that conversion (e.g., by having your own `strlen` that accepts `const char(&)[N]`), I expect it would work regardless of storage duration. I would appreciate an answer with a solid backing for that, which I don't have.

Comment: I believe this is because variables with automatic storage duration get created in the same area of memory, regardless of whether they are const-qualified or not. If you make your array static, the memory will be read-only and it should work.  You effectively did that when you put it into the global namespace instead of in main.

Comment: Some `const`s are just more `const` than others. I guess gcc considers the namespace-scope `cs` as being more of a constant expression than the local scope one for the purposes of `strlen()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard `strlen` is not `constepxr`, therefore, it cannot be used in `constexpr` context. However, GCC [knows about strlen](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), therefore it is able to compute the length of the string, in some circumstances - even if it is not mandated/permitted by the standard.

If you are concerned only by arrays, you can use [std::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get their size:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}
```